# How can I keep node locations fixed after drawing arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to keep centered first drawn node, node number 1 on the given example. It remains centered until I start drawing arrows. Hence, when I draw arrows on top of the figure everything shifts to left.

Is it possible to prevent shifting of nodes after drawing arrows and keep the first drawn node centered?

```
\documentclass[journal,twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
    backgrounds,
    fit,
    positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning, shapes.geometric, shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance=0.5cm and 1cm,
        FIT/.style = {draw,dashed, fill=yellow!30, inner sep=2mm, fit=#1},
        arrow/.style={->, >=stealth, semithick},
        arroww/.style={->, semithick},
        compute/.style={draw,semithick,
            append after command={%
                (\tikzlastnode.south west) edge[double=gray!50,double distance=2pt,
                line cap=rect,
                shorten >=-0.1pt,shorten <=-0.1pt]
                (\tikzlastnode.south east)}},
        Cylinder/.style={shape=cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw, shape aspect=0.2 ,font={\baselineskip=9pt}, inner xsep=+3pt,},
        N/.style = {circle,draw, draw=black, fill=white,minimum size=5mm, inner sep =1mm},
        ]

        \node[N] (w1) {1};
        \node[N, below=of w1,inner sep=1.5pt] (w2) {14};
        \node[N, below=of w2,inner sep=1.5pt] (w3) {2};
        \node[N, below=of w3,inner sep=1.5pt] (w4) {5};
        \node[N, below=of w4,inner sep=1.5pt,xshift=1cm] (w5) {3};
        \node[N, below=of w5,inner sep=1.5pt] (w6) {10};
        \node[N, below=of w6,inner sep=1.5pt] (w7) {7};
        \node[N, below=of w7,inner sep=1.5pt,xshift=-1cm] (w8) {11};
        \node[N, right=of w6,inner sep=1.5pt] (w9) {4};
        \node[N, below=of w8,inner sep=1.5pt] (w10) {9};
        \node[N, below=of w10,inner sep=1.5pt] (w11) {12};

        \draw[arroww]   (w4) edge (w8);
        \draw[arroww]   (w2) edge (w3);
        \draw[arroww]   (w3) edge (w4);
        \draw[arroww]   (w4) edge (w5);
        \draw[arroww]   (w5) edge (w6);
        \draw[arroww]   (w6) edge (w7);
        \draw[arroww]   (w7) edge (w8);
        \draw[arroww]   (w5) edge (w9);
        \draw[arroww, out=330,in=15,looseness=1]   (w3) edge (w8);
        \draw[arroww, out=330,in=90,looseness=1]   (w1) edge (w9);
        \draw[arroww, out=320,in=0,looseness=0.8]   (w1) edge (w8);
        \draw[arroww, out=320,in=0,looseness=1.4]   (w2) edge (w11);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{DAG.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

---

Afterwards, I have uncommented the lines for the arrow, and you can see that it has been shiftled to left:

[image]

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile unfortunately, the issue is in this line `\node[N,inner sep=1.5pt,above=of w1,xshift=-1cm] (w1) {1};`

Comment: @JamesT I just fixed my code

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz when I use overlay nodes and the caption collide on top of each other, could I ask a new question regarding to this?

Comment: Use the overlay option only on the elements which should not change the bounding box, e.g. the arrows. Don't use it for the nodes.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for very fast response!